# How to recording the video of webcam using the JMF?

Tags: java, webcam, video-capture, jmf

I create java Media player and finished Video player, Audio Player, taking snapshot, etc., But i can only capture the video using webcam. I want to record the video in hard disk. What I have to do for that..?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://www.mutong.com/fischer/java/usbcam/?